# z.show limit problem in python interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using python interpreter in zeppelin and I want to display pandas DataFrame through `z.show()` without limit in 1000 rows.

But when I increase `zeppelin.python.maxResult` then nothing changes and `z.show()` still display 1000 rows.

Can anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional workaround needed.

You did correctly with the modification of `zeppelin.python.maxResult` in the interpreter GUI. What you should try is the modification of the property `zeppelin.interpreter.output.limit` in `zeppelin-site.xml` in Zeppelin's conf file.

To modify `zeppelin-site.xml` you have to make a copy of `zeppelin-site.xml.template` and paste it as `zeppelin-site.xml`, then modify it.